# Will my previous project no longer be functional if i don't upgrade?

Tags: firebase

My previous project( which i developed as personal project)  included cloud functions.
I received an email regarding that all those who want to use cloud functions have to upgrade to blaze plan by june.
Will my prev project be no longer functional, if i dont upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please read the entire email carefully.**  It prescribes different courses of action depending on what you've previously done.  There's not enough information in your question to tell what exactly you personally have to do.

I think it's safe to say that if you don't take any action, you will not be able to deploy your functions any more.

I think it's also safe to say that if you don't upgrade your node runtime and your billing plan by the dates listed in the email, your function will not work any more.  The email says nothing about Firebase products other than Cloud Functions, so I would not expect changes to anything else.

If you have questions that are not addressed by the email (again, read it carefully), I suggest [reaching out to Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).